# Unknown command: 'auth' Type 'manage.py help' for usage

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-models, deployment

I'm using Django 3.1, and I'm unable to fix this issue. I'm running the following command `heroku run python manage.py auth zero`, but I am getting this error:

```
Running python manage.py auth zero on ⬢ dotescrow... up, run.1867 (Free)
Unknown command: 'auth'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
```

This is my `settings.py` file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts',
    'django_countries',
    'bootstrap3',
    # 'wallets',
    #  'frontend',
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to reverse the migrations in the app `auth`, try the following:

```sh
heroku run python manage.py migrate auth zero
```

The problem is that `manage.py` is expecting a command, and `auth` is not a command but a Django app.